# Write a duplicate rows in Flat File using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a source flat file, I want to read each row and create two more duplicate foreach row. What is the best way to achieve this ?

Example My flat file

```
ID_Col  Country_Col
1       CountryA
2       CountryA
3       CountryC
4       CountryB
```

What I want:

```
 ID_Col  Country_Col
 1       CountryA
 1       CountryB
 1       CountryC
 2       CountryA
 2       CountryB
 2       CountryC
 3       CountryA
 3       CountryB
 3       CountryC
 4       CountryA
 4       CountryB
 4       CountryC
```

Rows are created which values `Country B` and `Country C`.What is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Cross join to a table with three rows that contains `CountryB` and `CountryC`. Do you have an existing table with `CountryB` and `CountryC` as records in it? Is it always `CountryB` and `CountryC` no matter what is in the flat file?

Comment: Someone will of course suggest that you write C# script to do it. Are you comfortable with C#?

Comment: Country B and C not coming from table. If Flat file have Country A regardless any ID then add Country B and C to follow the same ID.. if flat file have Country B then add Country A and C and so on... basically Country A B and C will always there. I have a basic understanding with C#. But dont have idea how to start with this in ssis.

Comment: If we pursue to non C# solution, then first you need a table in the database that has three records: country A, countr B, country C. I will edit your question to make it clearer

Comment: Can you check my edit please. It seems that the actual country in the file is completely redundant right?

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid that what I want  to achieve, yes its completely redundant, How about C# Solution ? hows the flow ?

Comment: I won't suggest a C# solution. Someone else can. I don't think it's the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you load your flat file into a staging table and therefore already have a table called `MyStagingTable` with this data in it:

```
ID_Col  Country_Col
=====================
1       CountryA
2       CountryA
3       CountryC
4       CountryB
```

Also assuming you have a table called `AllCountries` with this in it:

```
Country_Name
===============
CountryA
CountryB
CountryC
```

Then you can write this query to get what you want:

```
SELECT S.ID_Col, C.Country_Name
FROM MyStagingTable S
CROSS JOIN 
AllCountries C
```

Which means you can put this query inside an execute SQL Task to load into a table

```
INSERT INTO FinalTable (ID_Col, Country_Name)
SELECT S.ID_Col, C.Country_Name
FROM MyStagingTable S
CROSS JOIN 
AllCountries C
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick. I’ll do this way and see how then accept this as answer. Btw, for the sake of knowledge, how to do achieve this by using c#. High level idea.

Comment: This is how you need to use the script component. This example adds a column: https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssis-script-component-as-transformation/. This example shows how to add rows instead: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4dbfcc3-f7df-4462-830e-e351cdc6dbc3/how-to-add-rows-with-script-component?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: I think you might be looking to replace AllCountries with (Select distinct Country_col from MyStagingTable)

Comment: But if all the countries aren’t present they won’t be returned.